# Handling partial database in Visual Studio database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-project

So we have a SQL Server database that is replicated from a 3rd party vendor's cloud down to our local database. Data in the tables is replicated down continuously from their cloud servers and occasionally they update the full database with new changes to structure. Their schema is the default dbo schema.

For reporting, we've added a second schema (let's call it abc) where we add some additional tables as well as some functions/stored procedures that reference the data in both the abc and dbo schemas. I have set up our abc schema in Visual Studio as a database project and it looks great, however, I can't deploy/publish anything because when it builds, it says it can't find tables that are in the dbo schema. Obviously that's just because we haven't created them in our database project because we've only setup the scripts for our abc schema.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to either ignore those errors or to look in the actual database (not the database project) for those tables?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a dacpac of the "base" database, then include that as a database reference using "same database, same server"?  That would keep the objects out of your project, but allow you to reference them in your code.

Comment: I assume it would be added in VS in the db project under References > Add Database Reference... ?

Comment: Correct. You'll just have to gen up a dacpac first. You might need to use sqlpackage.exe to do so.